# Could not find javascript runtime environment,ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0, therubyracer

I am trying to set up ruby 2.0 with rails 4 on my local machine. So after installing when i tried to generate scaffold it says "Could not find javascript runtime environment". To fix this issue I followed the following steps

1. Installed therubyracer gem (for windows)
2. Added those in gem file.
3. Started with new instance of cmd. (but error repeated)
4. Re-started my machine, but seems i can not fix this.

Please guide me on how to fix this so that i could get started with ruby2 and rails 4 on my machine.

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` after step 2?

Comment: Yes MikeDiet I did. Still no help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and this is what I found:

You need a javascript runtime library such as nodejs to solve this problem.

For Ubuntu users , try the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

For installing nodejs on systems using yum, try the following in the terminal:

```
yum -y install nodejs
```

Hope it helps :)